# Output for correct letter in hangman in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on creating hangman, and if a player correctly guesses a letter that appears multiple times in a word, it should replace the dashes with that letter in the dashes list, but it is returning separate lists with each position. If the secret_word is "checking code" how do I get the script to return "c__c____ c___" ? Here is the code:

```
secret_word = ''

def blank_string():
    global secret_word
    global blanks
    secret_word = input('Please type a word or phrase: ')
    blanks = ''
    for i in secret_word.lower():
        if i == ' ':
            blanks = blanks + ' '
        else:
            blanks = blanks + '_'
    print(blanks)

blank_string()

def guesses():
    misses = []
    list_secret_word = list(secret_word)
    letterGuess = input("Please guess a letter or type 'guess' to guess the whole word/phrase : ")
    if letterGuess.lower() == 'guess':
        wordGuess = input('what do you think the word/phrase is?: ')
        if wordGuess.lower() == secret_word.lower():
            print(f'Congratulations you have correctly guessed the word: {x.lower()}')
        else:
            print('sorry that is incorrect')
    elif len(letterGuess) > 1:
        raise ValueError('Please only enter one letter')
    for v in range(0,len(secret_word)):
            if letterGuess.lower() == list_secret_word[v]:
                letter_index = v
                blank_list = list(blanks)
                blank_list[v] = secret_word[v]
                print(blank_list)           
               
                



guesses()
```

Comment: Read up on [How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) and pick one from [`[python] hangman`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aanswer+%5Bpython%5D+hangman)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, you are resetting `blank_list` with every loop iteration:

```py
    for v in range(0,len(secret_word)):
            if letterGuess.lower() == list_secret_word[v]:
                                             # Each time the loop is run, blank_list is
                blank_list = list(blanks)    # replaced with the original value of blanks.
                blank_list[v] = secret_word[v]
                print(blank_list)
```

When you modify `blank_list`, it does not modify the `blanks` variable. Instead, you probably want to define `blank_list` outside the for loop and reuse it. For example:

```py
def guesses():
    blank_list = list(blanks)
    
    # First part of the function here
    # ...
    # Then:

    for v in range(0, len(secret_word)):
            if letterGuess.lower() == list_secret_word[v]:
                blank_list[v] = secret_word[v]
    # And print the new list after the for loop instead of with every iteration
    print(blank_list)
```

If you want to update the value of `blanks` with the new characters in `blank_list` after the for loop, you can do:

```py
blanks = "".join(blank_list)
```

This joins all of the characters in `blank_list` together with `""` (nothing) in between each character. Then you can print `blanks` instead of `blank_list`.